# Can a .ttl or .tql file be processed in python (3.x) without using RDFlib?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on DBpedia datasets which are in .ttl or .tql extensions. I want to parse the contents of the file into dict or lists without using RDFlib. Is this possible?
Below is a partial extract from the file.

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AmoeboidTaxa> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "AmoeboidTaxa"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AlbaniaHistory> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "AlbaniaHistory"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AsWeMayThink> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "AsWeMayThink"@en .
```

Comment: Did manage to get this done? I am facing the same problem. rdflib is not working for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution using [rdflib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib):

```
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()
g.parse('you_file.ext', format='turtle')
```

**UPDATE:**

I've realized that rdflib does not process by streaming. So, it turns out is very complicated to deal with very huge files (as dbpedia ones). So, what I've done was to iterate through dbpedia files and slice them into very small files and then process with rdflib as above.